# Can't migrate database. ActiveAdmin and Rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I added activeadmin in my Gemfile and run `rake db:migrate`

And see this:

> rake aborted!
>   An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>   Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank...

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

Thank you!

Comment: post the code of your migration

Comment: pull AA from up updated branch. maybe you could find this bug has been fixed. try `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: '0-6-stable'`

Comment: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (< 4, >= 3.0.0) ruby

    rails (4.0.2)`

Comment: Master branch is rails 4 compatible. You don't need to use 0-6-stable.

Comment: The bug has been fixed so pulling the latest master should do the trick. See here: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2284

Comment: i have already found this topic but i'm not understand what i'm should to make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulling the latest master should fix it. Make sure to run `bundle update activeadmin` to pull the latest code. Clean all previous generated code with `rails destroy active_admin:install`. Destroy the `admin_users` database table.

Run `rails generate active_admin:install` one more time.
If you are using `protected_attributes` gem you will need to add the line below before running `rake db:migrate` to `admin_user.rb.

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Also note if you had run rake db:migrate without the last line (attr_accessible) and error popped out, you need to **clean all previous generated code** as written in the guide. It won't work otherwise.